# IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf return gibberish

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop

I'm new to winapi and c/c++ and I try to print out the names of the icons on the desktop using IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf but for some reason I'm getting gibberish. Here is my code:

```
    int main() {
    HRESULT hr;
    IShellFolder* deskFolder;
    hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&deskFolder);
    IEnumIDList* listilist;
    deskFolder->EnumObjects(NULL, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS | SHCONTF_FOLDERS, &listilist);
    ITEMIDLIST* item;
    deskFolder->Release();
    while (listilist->Next(1, &item, NULL) == S_OK) {
        STRRET coo = {0};
        deskFolder->GetDisplayNameOf(item, SHGDN_INFOLDER, &coo);
        printf("%s\n", coo.cStr);
        item = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not checking `STRRET::uType`, and you probably want to use [`StrRetToBuf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strrettobufw) anyway.

Comment: IShellFolder, IEnumIDList are kinda legacy for clients and painful to use. You should instead get IShellItem objects, for example using SHGetKnownFolderItem(FOLDERID_Desktop, etc.) so you never have to use this clumsy STRRET type as you'll have IShellItem::GetDisplayName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shtypes/ns-shtypes-strret):

> **uType**
>
> Type: UINT
>
> A value that specifies the desired format of the string. This can be
> one of the following values.
>
> **STRRET_CSTR**
>
> The string is returned in the cStr member.
>
> **STRRET_OFFSET**
>
> The uOffset member value indicates the number of bytes
> from the beginning of the item identifier list where the string is
> located.
>
> **STRRET_WSTR**
>
> The string is at the address specified by pOleStr member.

You can check the `utype` parameter of `coo`:

```
printf("%d\n", coo.uType);
```

After checking, its return value is 0 (`STRRET_WSTR`), so you need to modify the code as

```
printf("%S\n", coo.pOleStr);
```